# Why is pandas merge slower when using an index, if it contains duplicate values?

Tags: python, pandas, merge

Been tinkering with `pd.merge()`, trying to get a feel for what's fast and what's not. One of the things that surprised me is that merging tables `foo` and `bar` is significantly faster if I merge on plain ole columns rather than making those columns the index and then merging on the their index, provided that the values contain duplicates.

## Illustration

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import timeit

np.random.seed(2020)
foo = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.choice(10**6, size=10**6, replace=True), 'Foo': 'dummy column'})
bar = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.choice(10**6, size=10**6, replace=True), 'Bar': 'dummy column'})

# column <-> column
timeit.timeit(lambda: pd.merge(left=foo, right=bar, on='A', how='inner'), number=10)  # 4.275

# index <-> column
foo.set_index('A', inplace=True)
timeit.timeit(lambda: pd.merge(left=foo, right=bar, left_index=True, right_on='A', how='inner'), number=10)  # 4.329

# index <-> index
bar.set_index('A', inplace=True)
timeit.timeit(lambda: pd.merge(left=foo, right=bar, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='inner'), number=10)  # 9.863
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the hood, both methods will call `_get_join_indexers` in pandas.core.reshape.merge. However, there is some difference in how this is called (https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py#L844).

- When you provide both `left_index=True` and `right_index=True`, what happens under the hood is essentially `left_index.join(right_index)`. `_get_join_indexers` gets called inside here
- When you don't provide both of `left_index=True` and `right_index=True`, `_get_join_indexers` is called more directly

So what is happening when we call `left_index.join(right_index)` that is slowing this down? The answer is that the `sort` arg is actually not propogated fully in the case when neither index is unique (as per this example) and is always set to `True` (https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.25.3/pandas/core/indexes/base.py#L3689).

In fact, if you look at the results, they aren't actually the same! The results when you use both the indices are sorted (even though the argument you pass into merge is `sort=False`). Note that if you do pass in `sort=True` to all ways of merging, the runtimes become roughly equivalent (as expected).

TL,DR: the `sort` kwarg is not correctly propogated and when merging on non-unique indices it is not obeyed (PR incoming!)